Vanishing of chow group of 0-cycles for affine, simplicial toric varieties
Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero.
Let $X$ be an affine, simplicial toric variety over $k$.
If $X$ has dimension one, then it is the affine line over the field $k$, so its divisor class group is zero. Since its Chow group of 0-dimensional cycles is isomorphic to its divisor class group, we have $A_0(X)=0$.
Is it true that for any $X$, we always have $A_0(X)=0$?

If $X$ is a projective toric variety then $A_0(X) = \mathbb{Z}$ (this is true because it's resolution is rationally connected), and then the localization exact sequence implies that for any nontrivial open subset $A_0(U) = 0$.

@Evgeny Shinder Thank you very much for your kind guidance and help.
